# sshd croaks daily with "invalid open call: O_CREAT without mode"

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-12.04

One of my servers has daily issues.
When I log in via SSH or SFTP, I get the error below. 
When restoring it via a remote console, I need to purge and reinstall openssh-server.
This is not enough, I also need to reboot and then it works again for 1 day.

I have done this procedure 12 days in a row now but can't find a permanent solution.

```
*** invalid open call: O_CREAT without mode ***: sshd: root@pts/0 terminated
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__fortify_fail+0x37)[0x7fa616e60387]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0xeb3d1)[0x7fa616e413d1]
sshd: root@pts/0[0x41a422]
sshd: root@pts/0[0x41a8cb]
sshd: root@pts/0[0x41ad98]
sshd: root@pts/0[0x409630]
sshd: root@pts/0[0x40f9ed]
sshd: root@pts/0[0x410cb6]
sshd: root@pts/0[0x411874]
sshd: root@pts/0[0x411df6]
sshd: root@pts/0[0x40b253]
sshd: root@pts/0[0x42bd04]
sshd: root@pts/0[0x40c9cb]
sshd: root@pts/0[0x412079]
sshd: root@pts/0[0x4061a2]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xed)[0x7fa616d7776d]
sshd: root@pts/0[0x407635]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00447000 r-xp 00000000 09:02 11665809                           /usr/sbin/sshd
00647000-00648000 r--p 00047000 09:02 11665809                           /usr/sbin/sshd
```

Comment: Is this an actual server, a virtual server, or a containerised server?  If the latter two, technology?  In all cases, distro and version?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Daily sftp stops working, and weekly sshd fails and needs reinstall](http://serverfault.com/questions/658614/daily-sftp-stops-working-and-weekly-sshd-fails-and-needs-reinstall)

Comment: AndrewSchulman no this is a entirely different issue.

@MadHatter Its Ubuntu 12.04 LTS minimal

Comment: And the virtualisation question?

Comment: Your server is possibly compromised.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSH invalid open call: O\_CREAT without mode](http://serverfault.com/questions/527395/ssh-invalid-open-call-o-creat-without-mode)